# When are frontier orbitals a better way to explain reactivity than the Hammond Postulate?

Tags: organic-chemistry

When explaining the *ortho, para* directing ability of electron donating groups in electrophilic aromatic substitution, one can use either frontier orbitals or the Hammond Postulate. The frontier orbital argument says that the HOMO has a higher coefficient on the *ortho* and *para* carbons, so the reaction primarily occurs on those carbons due to the better HOMO-LUMO interaction (I think you could evaluate the impact of this overlap quantitatively by looking at the effect of overlap on the resonance integral in the third term of the Klopman-Salem equation).

Using the Hammond Postulate, one can argue that the transition state of the addition of the electrophile to the aromatic ring resembles the intermediate because the reaction is highly endothermic and the energy of the transition state is similar to the energy of the intermediate. The intermediate (and therefore transition state) energy is lowest when the electrophile is added to an *ortho* or *para* position, because in these cases there is a resonance form with a positive charge on the carbon bonded to the donating substituent, which stabilizes the charge. This lower-energy transition state leads to a faster reaction.

Are both of these arguments valid? In general, are there certain situations where one approach is better, or in which each would lead to different predictions about reactivity? Do both of these methods account for the same factors? For example, how would frontier orbital theory and the Klopman-Salem equation account for the stabilization of positive charge by the electron-donating group?

One idea I have is that the relative importance of the frontier orbital argument may depend on how much the electron donating group affects the coefficients of the HOMO. For example, there is more electron density on the *ortho* and *para* carbons when the substituent is OMe or NH2 than when the substituent is CH3. Would this lead to an increased difference in HOMO-LUMO overlap between an electrophile attacking an *ortho*/*para* carbon and an electrophile attacking a *meta* carbon, which would mean that the frontier orbital considerations lead to more selectivity?